# Good way to search array for string and return those objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

So I'm almost done with this guest list front-end application I've been working on. The last thing I want to do is allow a string to be passed to filter the list by name. So by subscribing to a user inputting some name into a field, I should be able to use this ko computed function for searching the array in this different way. Keep in mind that self.guests is an array of guest objects.

```
self.displayResults = ko.computed(function(){
    if(self.displayTypeOf() == 'slice'){
        var ary = self.guests.slice(self.startValue(),self.endValue());
        console.log(ary)
        return ary
    }else if(self.displayTypeOf() == 'string'){
        //Code I need goes here
    }
});
```

You can see that normally the list is computed with a sliced section of the list, when the user begins typing something in the input, I will override and update this computed list using the search array function I'm asking for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Artem's answer may be what you're looking for but for clarity, since guests is an array of objects, what does a Guest object look like/what object variable would the string be compared against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to `ko.utils.arrayFilter` utility function for filtering:

```
self.displayResults = ko.computed(function(){
    if(self.displayTypeOf() == 'slice'){
        var ary = self.guests.slice(self.startValue(),self.endValue());
        console.log(ary)
        return ary
    }else if(self.displayTypeOf() == 'string'){
        // Init filter
        var filter = self.SomeValue();
        var ary = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.guests(), function(item) {
           return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(item.name().toLowerCase(), filter);
        });
        console.log(ary);
        return ary;
    }
});
```

Read more about ko utils methods here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

Comment: Thank you sir, although luckily I was able to find out immediately that stringStartsWith is not included in the min CDN. I have to copy it from the source.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array::filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
var guestlist = [ 'Foo Bar', 'Doo Bar', 'Foo Doo', ... ];

function guestFilter(element) {
    return element.indexOf('Bar') > 0;
}

guestlist.filter(guestFilter); // [ 'Foo Bar', 'Doo Bar' ]
```